# Host does not allow remote connection, so how do I transfer data to my WordPress site?

Tags: php, multisite, database

I spent the last week trying to get my PHP code on my website to connect to my remote "personal" computer to display some data on a webpage. I just found out today from my web host (ipage)

"our platform does not allow remote database connections in either directions. I apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused."

So I am wondering if there is any other method to get data from a remote database to my website. Whether it is live data or a code I have to run every day or so; I would like to display this info on my site.

Comment: Are you just trying to export your local database to use it in your hosted website? If so, you can just export a sql file from whatever db software you are using in your computer, and then import it to your website using something like PHPMyAdmin which most shared hosts have.

Comment: It seems to be fairly normal for hosts not to allow remote connections. You will need to operate over the protocols your host allows-- HTTP and FTP, I'd guess. Can you explain exactly what you want to transfer?

Comment: Your question does not really make it clear what you are trying to achive. If you want to do remote mainteance of your mysql db I would suggest using an http wrapper (like HTTPTunnel GUI) or an SQL management tool that includes an http tunnel script (like SQLyog). If you want to transfer data for production use on a regular base I would suggest using any kind of self build or plugin web api (JSON/XML API) to transfer the data.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this question was clear enough. I host online game servers on my personal computer and the info is sent to the database on my personal computer. So everything is "local". I also have a website hosted through ipage which does not allow any remote database connections. I originally wanted to remote connect so that I can have live data (player health, scores, etc) displayed on my website, but since this is not possible I am looking for an alternative. Any way to send this data to a different location that can be pulled into my website in a different manner?